# PySpark execute all test cases in a directory

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to develop a script which will run all the spark sql queries kept in a directory.
I have been able to do that in Python, but pyspark is a different game.
Below is the python script I use to read and execute all query files in a directory.

> import sys,csv,sqlite3,codecs,unicodedata, string,glob, os,c
>   conn=psycopg2.connect(database="xxx", user="xxxx", password="xxxx",
>   host="localhost", port="5432") cur = conn.cursor() print("done")
>
> with open("*.txt", "r") as ins:  for line in ins:
>   words=line.split('|')    print(words)    query=words[0]
>   pmicode=words[1]    print(query)
>        cur = conn.cursor()
>        cur.execute(query) conn.commit() conn.close()

Is it possible to replicate this in PySpark ?

Thanks,
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want pyspark to pull data from the postgres database that you're using in this python script.

If the current code in Python is something like:

```
import sys, csv, sqlite3, codecs, unicodedata, string, glob, os
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="xxx", user="xxxx", password="xxxx", host="localhost", port="5432")
cur = conn.cursor()
print("done")

def runSQL(query):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    conn.commit()

with open("*.txt", "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        words = line.split('|')
        print(words)
        query = words[0]
        pmicode = words[1]
        print(query)

conn.close()
```

The equivalent would be to use JDBC to connect and execute command with a sqlContext:

```
import sys, csv, sqlite3, codecs, unicodedata, string, glob, os
postgres_url = 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database'
properties = {"user": "xxxx", "password": "xxxx"}
print("done")

def runSQL(query):
    return sqlContext.read.jdbc(
        url=postgres_url,
        table="( {0} ) TEMPDB_SPARK_DELINQ".format(query)

with open("*.txt", "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        words = line.split('|')
        print(words)
        query = words[0]
        pmicode = words[1]
        print(query)
        runSQL(query)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to respond. Unfortunately it does not solve my usecase. I'm looking to run all query files in a directory. The above script will do that for Postgres. But I am using a combination of SparkSQL and PySpark. That's why the question "PySpark execute all test cases in a directory".